# High charts not displaying date correctly in x axis per epoch?

Tags: highcharts

Two Part Q:

1. Why is high charts not correctly aligning and displaying the following date on the x axis?
2. How can I align the date on the x axis with the points in each series?

I have tried adjusting to tickinterval to various values but to no avail on either issue.

```
tickPixelInterval: 200
```

Fiddle->http://jsfiddle.net/EwpWh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use datetime axis instead of linear, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/EwpWh/5/

```
                           xAxis: {
                                type: 'datetime',
                                labels: {
                                    formatter: function () {
                                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d', this.value);
                                    }
                                },
                                tickPixelInterval: 200
                            },
```

However if you want to have ticks exactly in the same place as points are, you need to use one of:

- tickPositions: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositions
- tickPositioner: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Thanks. However, per http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/EwpWh/5/ "5/8" is still being displayed twice.

Comment: Coming back to this one again but for some reason 5/8 is showing up twice in the x axis for date even after adding datetime as type?

Comment: Instead of using `tickPixelInterval`, try to set `tickInterval` to 1day.